# PHP Include Sleep on Main File

Tags: php

I've got an a simple include for my new project.

What happens is my included file checks a few functions and outputs the results.

If there is any kind of **error** I want a simple redirect to happen.

The problem I'm having is that the rest of the main file (which has the include on) keeps loading for a few seconds, before the redirect can be complete.

Is there possibly a way of **sleeping** the main file while the checks are made?

Thanks!

**EDIT @dan:**

*Part of the included file:*

```
function redirect($url) {
    if(!headers_sent()) {
        header('Location: '.$url);
        exit;
    } else {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
        echo 'window.location.href="'.$url.'";';
        echo '</script>';
        echo '<noscript>';
        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url='.$url.'" />';
        echo '</noscript>';
        exit;
    }
}

$url = "http://www.whatever.com/";
redirect($url);    
exit;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `die` or `exit` to stop execution when you get to the point you want to redirect.

```
header("Location: http://www.example.com");
exit;
```

Comment: Didn't seem to work. Still loaded the main file before redirection.

Comment: Since it's not possible that execution continues after `exit`, it's now time for you to share your actual code. Please edit it into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Are you including PHP along with HTML?

If you put all your HTML into PHP strings and don't output them until your processing is complete, that should work.

Comment: Or use the output buffering functions. [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php)

Answer (score 0):

The few seconds wait you're seeing is actually the browser sending off the redirect request and waiting for a response. Unless the link between you and the client has zero latency, and your server can respond instantly, there will always be a pause for redirect.